Creating constexpr map filled by calls to a constexpr function in C++ 17
I have a constexpr function that calculates CRC at compile time. I need to create a map between CRCs that are generated by this function and string inputs and use them in runtime (Even better if it is also possible to use it in compile time too).
The map creation process should be from withing this constexpr function so it automatically logs all CRCs that are generated. Also it doesn't necessarily needs to be a map. Only key value pairs that could be looked up.
I'm using C++ 17 by the way.
This is my function signature:
template <size_t length>
static constexpr unsigned int getCrc32(const char (&str)[length])
{
        //calculate compile time CRC

        // What I need should happen here: saving the calculated
        // CRC and string to be accessed outside later
}

I tried different ways with templates and other things but I either end up with compiling code with undefined behavior or unmodifiable contexpr wall.

You cannot have constexpr std::map, you can have constexpr std::array<std::pair<unsigned int, const char*>> (with pointer with static storage).

@Jarod42 I know, the question is how to fill it by each call to this function?

So what did you try and what didn't work? E.g. this seems to be simple enough: constexpr Result r1{"abc", getCrc32("abc")}; assuming you have some struct Result {const char* in; unsigned int out;};

@pptaszni Map filling needs to happen inside this function but results gets accessed from outside. I don't want to make user goes and adds his usages manually to a list. It should log generated crcs automatically. I'll update the question to make it clearer

Expected example usage might clarify your needs.

So you don't want to provide a list/tuple of c-string pointer, but register them from the function call, right?

Now understood, but it sounds difficult (impossible?). You want the constexpr function to modify some storage while (possibly runtime dependent) calling this function.

@Jarod42 Yeah exactly,

@pptaszni It's all compile time. only access is in runtime, but yes, I need to modify some sort of global storage or anything else possible to store whatever was generated by this function and its inputs. Yeah, sounds so difficult and almost impossible that's why I posted it here as some last measure :(.

Could you use something like constexpr auto map = MyMap.push_back<string_pointer>(); constexpr auto map2 = MyMap.push_back<string_pointer2>(); map2.find(42)? As mutating some global state from within a constexpr function is not constexpr...

(Deprecated) stateful metaprogramming might allow to have your global map, but it would be usable only in one TU anyway, so providing the list manually seems simpler.
